# Retrieve all sub users when entered a search term in LDAP

Tags: java, tree, active-directory

I am looking for a query, when entered a name it should check whether there are any sub employees reporting to that entered name. If there are any, then it should return all the list of child users(employees) and sub child users reporting to that employee.

I wrote a query, when entered a username, it gets **all** the data associated with him, but I am confused now how to get only the users & sub-users & sub-sub users names that report to that search term.

Is there a way to do it with AD or do I need to implement DFS search? If either option, then please give me some hints to do it.

```
    try {
                // Create Initial Context
                LdapContext ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
                // ctxGC.setRequestControls(null);

                String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + searchTerm + ")(!(displayName=ADM*)))";
                NamingEnumeration<?> namingEnum = ctxGC.search("OU=User,DC=emea,DC=xyz,DC=biz", searchFilter, getSearchControls());

        Deque<Node> stack = new ArrayDeque<Node>(); // Do I need to implement tree here or is there any other way to get sub users info from LDAP search??



                while (namingEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
                    SearchResult result = (SearchResult) namingEnum.next();
                    Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
                    if (attrs != null) {
                        NamingEnumeration ne = attrs.getAll();

                        while (ne.hasMore()) {
                            Attribute attr = (Attribute) ne.next();

                }
            }
}
            namingEnum.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SearchControls getSearchControls() {
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(new String[]{"*"});
        return searchCtls;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of users reporting to a manager, I just need to change the search filter query and retrieve the manager credentials, then it returns the list of all users that are reporting to that person. If there are no users reporting to him, then it returns nothing.

So, the `searchFilter` need to be changed like the following.

```
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(manager=CN=Its\\\\, Zaif,OU=xx,OU=xx,OU=StandardUser,OU=xx,DC=emea,DC=xyz,DC=biz) (!(displayName=ADM*)))";
```